# How to show custom date ranges in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In GA, there are 6 pre-defined date ranges, which are fairly useless.

Is there a way to create new date ranges in the drop down menu?  I'd like to add YTD, MTD, Last Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the closest you'll get is the Custom date range which cannot be saved. Having selected your custom range, you could do YTD and MTD with the "Compare to" list. You can also easily just type in your range, rather than selecting from the calendar picker.